# Android efficient matrix library

Tags: android, matrix

Is there any efficient linear algebra library for android? I need to compute matrices of different sizes(also bigger than 4x4) and rectangular too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JScience library](http://jscience.org/) contains matrix and other linear algebra support. There are others too. Take care to benchmark using realistic scenarios because there can be significant differences, and some libraries only pay for themselves on large problems while more simpler libraries then are no longer usable.

Answer (score 1):

RenderScript added IntrinsicBLAS for the large matrix multiplications.
You can find it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBLAS.html